# Use of multi threading to execute SQL statements

Tags: c#, sql, .net, multithreading, oracle

I have code that carries out data retrieval - basically executes anything from 3 to 12 SQL (oracle) read statements to retrieve data about an object.

Unfortunantly its running slowly (no SQL statement in particular, its just the fact I have so many of them - and they take around 0.2 seconds per statement, which can mean over 2 secs for the code to complete).

I am looking into ways of improving the performance. One way is to merge some of the tables into a single query (which can reduce the combined results by 0.5 secs). However it doesn't make sense to merge the rest since there will only be data there under certain cicumstances, and trying to determine when there is data there to marshal could get tricky.

I am considering introducing threading into my program, so after the initial query, I would spawn a thread for each of the other queries, so they are executed at the same time. However I have never used threading and am wary of introducing deadlocks or other pit falls.

Currently the other queries marshal the results into different sections of the SAME object. Would this cause any issues (i.e. since we are accessing/updating the same object in different threads though different sections/fields within the object?). Would it be better to return the results and marshal into the object after all the threads have finished?

I know these types of questions are hard to answer since its more general advice, but I would appreciate if anyone thought it was a good idea, or had other suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if this is an XY-problem. Are you sure it's necessary to do 3-12 roundtrips to get data for what is effectively a single entity? Why is the data spread over your tiers in such a way that you can't get this down to a single query? Throwing threads at an IO problem usually doesn't work that well.

Comment: Look's like he is not IO bound yet, threading do help to the certain degree.

Comment: Is it right that you execute 3 to 12 queries per single object instance? How many objects normally loaded from DB (100, 1000, 1000000, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing only reading (select from) - don't worry about deadlocks. Oracle readings are not blockable (mostly). The biggest problem with threading queries to oracle would be how to deal with connections. To create connection, run a query and close connection  - is very very very bad. Connections are expensive. They are also limited, so you don't want to create one million connections to execute your logic.

As a result, you would use some sort of connection pool and put your queries in a queue.

Also, I hope you are using bind variables and not string concatenation to pass queries to oracle.

In general, I would collect all the data (better in one query) and only then update the object. You could also consider to brake your object into it sections.

Comment: You mean the oracle providers are so stupid they do not implement the connection pooling that is mandatory for C# / ADO.NET connection management? Really? Otherwise opening a new connection is dead cheap. COnnection pooling is standard in .NET since v1.

Comment: @TomTom - Are you saying that if I try to open 10^6 connections I will be provided with some pool instead? Where is a boundry that my X connections will be AUTOMATICALLY replaced with Y(<<X) and a queue?

Comment: @TomTom - If you comment was about not to implement pooling yourself - 100% agree.

Comment: When you close a connection it is supposed to go back into the standard pool. http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ shows the oracle connection strings and how to control the pool size. It is a standard behavior to pool connections in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see that you can specify to use pooling when connecting to DB and it will be transparent for the application. But you need to configure it. And to configure it you need to know about pooling, right? It is not automatic, otherwise I would call this solution scary.

Comment: Except that a lookg into the documentation - which you should sometimes do - gives you default values for pooling. Ups. So it IS automatic - http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featConnecting.htm. FOr heavy use you may want to modify that (especially the max pool size of 5). Nothing scary for competent programmers here. This is standard since more than 15 years.

Comment: The reason, I started with pooling is that user2026086 goes from 1 thread to more than one and I bet his connection is not configured for pooling. He might even not need to do that if DBAs are using shared pool model. But it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Ok, so pooling is ON by default. Your new link do convince me in your point. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response, our framework handles connection pools and my initial testing of creating threads to call methods to query tables seems to have worked ok, with the exception of some child treads data being missing because it didn't seem to complete in time before the main thread had mapped the data from the sections the child thread was updating.

Answer (score 0):

Threading workss perfectly. 2 years ago I did a project that used a multi strage / multi threading approeach to push data into a oracle database (and pull some data out of it for updates).

I basicallly used a staged approach (a request would go through multiple stages, get consumed there and new data be pusehd to the next stage) and every stage used a configurable thread pool, which would take a message, process it and post the new messages.

We used I think at that time close to 200 threads to process about a million SQL statements per minute (hitting an Oracle Exadata that was really getting some work out of that).

So, multithreading "just works" - obviously if you know how to do it and you have to get your architecture and the sql statements nice and non blocking.  Databases in general are perfectly calable of handling multiple threads.

Now, for details: THAT DEPENDS.

Example:

> Currently the other queries marshal the results into different
>   sections of the SAME object. Would this cause any issues (i.e. since
>   we are accessing/updating the same object in different threads though
>   different sections/fields within the object?)

Absolutely no problem as long as:

- You make suer all updates are finished before moving the object to the next phase and
- The updates do not overlap or have a cardinality (1 must finish for 2 to have the required data).

These are implementation details and it is really hard to make a generic answer for those (totally impossible). Especially as this is multi threading 101 - and has nothing to do with any database access.

In general - you will also have to tune the number of threads. .NET can not do that itself - as it will see the CPU not busy and spawn up more threads, even if the database server is the bottleneck. This is why we went with multiple stages - so we could tune the number of threads depending what they do (and the last stage used bulk inserting to insert the aggregated data into temporary staging tables with a small number of threads, moving a lot of data in every statement - this will require some tuning possibilities to not totally overload the database side).

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response, its appreciated. I very roughly/quickly added code to introduce threading, 6 threads each reading different tables/data and updating different parts of the same object. Right off I reduced the time from over 2 seconds to <0.6 seconds, so it looks like its a distinct solution to this issue. One thing though, is there an easy way to get the main thread to wait until all child threads end, there were a couple cases that the main thread completed without some of the data in one of the child threads?